# Spring @Bean at method returning already created bean

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired

I have below class StaticDataCachesServerBean which is autowired by it's interface i.e.

```
@Autowired 
private StaticDataCaches staticDataCaches;
```

in some another class

I already created instance of `sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache` in init method of `StaticDataCachesServerBean` class. As per my understanding if annotate `sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache` with `@Bean` won't make any impact as instance is already created and same is returned when method is called.
Is my understanding correct?

What will happen if I don't annotate `sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache()` method with `@Bean` and what will happen if I annotate with `@Bean`?

```
@Configuration
public class StaticDataCachesServerBean implements StaticDataCaches {

    @Autowired
    private CerebrumApplication cerebrumApplication;
    private SdcUserCache sdcUserCache;
    private SdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        sdcUserCache = new SdcUserCacheImpl(
                new CacheUserProviderImpl(cerebrumApplication.getCacheProvider()));
        sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache= new SdcAutoAssignmentRuleCacheImpl(
                new CacheSdcAutoAssignmentRuleProviderImpl(cerebrumApplication.getCacheProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public SdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache() {
        return sdcAutoAssignmentRuleCache;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `@Bean` might return `null` as there is no guarantee that the `init` method has been invoked before calling the `@Bean`. Adding `@Bean` makes it a spring managed bean and thus it can receive callbacks etc.

Comment: why you can't check "What will happen if....?"