# May Spring @Bean methods return instance fields?

Tags: java, spring

The following Spring bean declaration appears to run and behave "as expected":

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    private final Foo foo;

    public AppConfig() {
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

where "as expected" means "nothing is *obviously* wrong".

Supposing that `Foo` has some complex lifecycle (e.g. manages external resources with `AutoCloseable`), is that a valid and sensible declaration of `foo()`? All of the examples I can find, official and not, indicate that the `foo` instance should be instantiated inside `foo()`, not stored in and retrieved from a field. However, I can find no definitive information in any documentation that this should or should not be safe.

The most relevant documentation I can find is about the Spring IoC bean lifecycle, for instance https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes. Reading between the lines, a `singleton` or `application` scoped bean, say, would be effectively valid because by the time it *ceases* to be valid the application is no longer alive. Since `singleton` is the default scope, the declaration above becomes implicitly valid.

Even with the appropriate scoping, suppose you introduce an alternative, profile-specific declaration

```
@Bean("foo")
@Profile("!test")
public Foo realFoo() {
    return this.foo;
}

@Bean("foo")
@Profile("test")
public Foo testFoo() {
    return new TestFoo();
}
```

Will `this.foo` now always be instantiated, even when activating the `test` profile? If so, does Spring still manage `realFoo()`'s value even though that bean is supposed to be inactive?

This question is not a duplicate of [Spring @Bean at method returning already created bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45183164/482758), which *begs the question*, but that question *may* correctly identify the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose benefits of what Spring IoC have to offer if you store it in the field and may even lead to unexpected behavior with certains scopes.

This will work if scope is `singleton` or `application` as it will only invoke `foo()` only once. But if the scope is changed to `protoptype` (creating a new instance everytime). Then it could cause unexpected behavior. Because you store `foo` in a field, so it will still behave as `singleton`, because it always points to the same instance.

If you initiate classes in your constructor it will always initiate, even if the profile is not active. Spring can not (and shouldn't) detect where instances are initiated. Spring IoC will not invoke the method if the profile isn't active. Along with the explanation above it will be safer to initiate instances in the method itself.